# Recent restrictions traveling to Morocco due to Ebola

Tags: health, morocco

As of October 19, 2014, what is the status of the Ebola Outbreak that may impact travel in Morocco?  Are there any cases and/or restrictions on travel to or from Morocco?

Answer (score 3):

Morocco has a very different climate and is separated from affected countries by a huge desert (and a few other things as well). It's on the African continent of course but that's not a good reason to be concerned and, unlike e.g. the US, there has never ever been a single case of Ebola virus disease in Morocco, let alone active transmission of the disease at the moment.

That said, Royal Air Maroc is – together with Brussels Airlines – the only major carrier to serve Liberia. Consequently, [there are apparently some restrictions/screening taking place in Casablanca](http://www.royalairmaroc.com/ma-en/Travel-Info/Ebola-Alert).

Comment: @pnuts Who said anything about Paris or Guinea?

Comment: @pnuts Not sure I follow you, are you confusing this with another question? I don't see any reference to Conakry or any question about Paris…